# When should I expect the NVidia 302+ driver to be available?

Tags: drivers, nvidia, updates

Nvidia [has released a driver with RandR support](http://www.phoronix.com/scan.php?page=news_item&px=MTA5NTY) (version 302, just this week).

It looks like this would probably show up first in the [X Updates ppa](https://launchpad.net/~ubuntu-x-swat/+archive/x-updates).

How long does it typically take for a new upstream release to land in the X Updates PPA?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The newest proprietary Nvidia drivers (including Nvidia 302.07) are available from [`ppa:graphics-drivers/ppa`](https://launchpad.net/~graphics-drivers/+archive/ubuntu/ppa).

For details see: [How do I install the Nvidia drivers?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/61396/how-do-i-install-the-nvidia-drivers/61433#61433)

---

The [Xorg-edgers ppa](https://launchpad.net/~xorg-edgers/+archive/ppa) now is for bleeding edge **open source graphics** drivers:

> **Note:** The drivers obtained from there are bleeding edge. So they are not considered as stable and may lead to system instabilites, or in the worst case to a broken system that can't boot any more. Please take the time to read the notices for this ppa and how to remove it in case things break.

Comment: Nice! Thanks. Does this warning (still) apply to precise? `Note: [ppa-purge] currently has issues in oneiric and later because ppa-purge does not work with multiarch.` If so, I may wait for it to show up in X Updates instead of sampling the crack... it's got tons of packages in it.

Comment: @bstpierre: haven't tried myself but aptitude should now be able to handle multiarch better. If there are no more issues with ppa-purge I don't know.